# AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'First_Name'

Tags: django, django-models

i encountered the following problem when i try to migrate list of models one of which contains a ManyToMany field.

```
class Item(models.Model):

File "C:\Users\helin\Downloads\Django\E-commerce\Farmers\Farmersapp\models.py", line 60, in Item

sluger = farmer.First_Name

AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'First_Name'

Below are the models i created.any help is appreciated.Thank you 

class Farmer(models.Model):

id = models.AutoField(default=1,primary_key=True)
First_Name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=15)




def __str__(self):
    return self.First_Name+" "+self.Last_Name

def get_farmer(self):
    return self.farmer.First_Name+" " +self.farmer.Last_Name
```

class Item(models.Model):

```
id = models.AutoField(default=1,primary_key=True)
category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=6)
price = models.FloatField()
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
image = models.ImageField()
farmer = models.ManyToManyField(Farmer, through='ItemAmount',related_name='item')
sluger = farmer.First_Name
slug = models.SlugField(default=sluger)



def __str__(self):
    return self.category
```

class ItemAmount(models.Model):

```
farmer = models.ForeignKey(Farmer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Comment: Since it is a m2m relation, there can be *zero*, *one* or more farmers. Hence the error.

Comment: so how can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, would suggest to take a look at [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), like lowercase attribute names, etc.

---

Django auto-creates `id` primary-key field on every model, unless other field is set as primary-key. So, this part can be safely avoided.

`get_farmer` method - how is it different from **str**? Also, these are `model instance` methods (`(self)`), so there is no `self.farmer` field on `Farmer` object - this will fail.

```
class Farmer(models.Model):
    # id AutoFied is  created by default by django, so no need to specify
    # id = models.AutoField(default=1,primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

---

`farmer = models.ManyToManyField()` - as it is ManyToMany, this means many farmers, so it is better to name field `farmers`, also same applies to reverse relation - Farmer might have multiple items - `related_name=items`.

`sluger` - is it a field? Also, it might have many farmers, so which one to pick?
`slug` - referencing self fields in default is not good idea, better set default in forms.

You can make `slug` CharField and set its value in `save()` method for example.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    # id AutoFied is  created by default by django, so no need to specify
    # id = models.AutoField(default=1,primary_key=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=6)
    price = models.FloatField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField()
    farmers = models.ManyToManyField(
        Farmer,
        through='ItemAmount',related_name='items'
    )
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

You can start with minimum working models and add new fields / methods one by one - it would be easier to debug and you will have base working app.

Comment: after solving the above error i got another one when i try to concatenate an object of farmer class with __str__ function.                                                                       
     return self.category +" by" +self.farmers
TypeError: Can't convert 'ManyRelatedManager' object to str implicitly

Comment: `farmers` is a ManyToMany relations, that means you actually get QuerySet object when accessing it. You can use some method to get names of all farmers of this item, like `def farmer_names: return ",".join([str(farmer) for farmer in self.farmers])`

Comment: thanks again,but the above answer didn't exactly generate the answer i was looking for.  I wanted to pair a farmer with an item which was presented by that particular farmer.  i wrote this line trying to match them => self.category +" by" +self.farmers .

Comment: Sorry, bit confused. `__str__` is one object's/instance method to get its string representation. If calling `str(Farmer())` - self in it will we that farmer instance. Also, Farmer and Item are related via `ManyToMany` relation, which means when accessing `Farmer.items` or `Item.farmers` - result is a list (QuerySet actually), not one object. A more clear example might be object class instance (Farmer(), Item()), which method to call on it, and expected result, .i.e. `str(Farmer()) == 'John Doe'`

Comment: sorry, i didn't quite understand the answer.what exactly shall i do to solve the problem.OR what you do recommend i do to solve the problem

Comment: Need more specific problem description. On which model instance what method should be called and what should be expected result? (i.e. `str(Farmer()) == 'John Doe'`)

Comment: On the Item model you can see there is a m2m relationship object to class Farmer named farmer.what i want to do is call the farmer that is related to that particular item on the item's __str__ function. this means....=> def __str__(): return self.category +" by" +self.farmers.First_Name. i saw that this concatenation of 2 different class object is possible on a video. but that is not working for me.